# PHP cURL causing massive server load on error?

Tags: php, curl

I'm currently making a PHP site that gets his data from an API. At first cURL seemed to do that perfectly, but if the API returns an empty response (and we make the request again, because we can't give a correct response without it) it seems to spawn a child process. This didn't use too much CPU when developing, but in production it can get as high as 150% CPU load.

Code used to get data from the API:

```
while (empty($output )) {
$ch = curl_init();
set_curl($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://domain.com");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: try to `curl_close($ch)` before last line `}`

Comment: Have you tried to use functions as `curl_getinfo()` or `curl_error()` to analyze why the response is empty? Like: `$info = curl_getinfo($ch)`

Comment: @Kim Alexander I'll try that

Comment: What is `set_curl($ch);` doing exactly? Also, you should put `$ch = curl_init();` outside of your `while()` loop. My guess would be that the loop is executing an exponential number of times for whatever reason and `curl_init()` is hogging your CPU...Also, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: You should find a better way of pooling the URL for what you want. Or at least put a `sleep()` in the `while` loop so that it doesn't hog all the CPU. Also avoid re-setting the curl object in the loop. At best leave only the `curl_exec()` in the loop if things don't change with each loop.

Comment: What kind of API gives an “empty” response, and wants that to be interpreted as “hey, try that same request again right away!” …?

Comment: @CBroe Is driving at the major problem here.  I think you need to revisit your retry strategy.  Just blindly retrying is a really poor approach.

Comment: I wouldn't loop this request.  Put it in a function or class method and compare the output with what is expected and if it does not match then run the function again.